# can't get jQuery click to register on elements correctly

Tags: jquery

see the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Hejm/8/)

i'm trying to get the 'read more' links to slide down and show the hidden content when clicked, but i can't seem to get the click function registered correctly. did i do something obviously wrong?

basic html layout

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="aHidden">some long text here</div> <!--defaulted hidden with css-->
    <div id="aBtn" class="bio-readMore">read more...</div>
</div>
```

here's the jQuery i'm trying to use to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").each(function(idx) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('bio-readMore')) {
            var thename = this.id.replace("Btn", "Hidden");
            var sel = "#" + thename;
            $(sel).click(function() {
                alert("running click for element with value " + this.id);
                if ($(this).is(":hidden")) {
                    $(this).slideDown("slow");
                } else {
                    $(this).slideUp();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: I don't get the logic behind `$(sel).click(function() { if ($(this).is(":hidden")) {` : how do you think you'll click on a hidden element ?

Comment: they don't. when they click on a certain 'read more' div, i need to expand a div above it that is collapsed with a similar name (aHidden instead of aBtn)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With your existing markup you could easily replace your click registration with the following:

```
$(".bio-readMore").on("click", function(){
    $(this).prev().slideToggle();
});
```

[**​jsfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Hejm/13/)

If you want to fix your code you have some of your selectors reversed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").each(function(idx) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('bio-readMore')) {
            var thename = this.id.replace("Btn", "Hidden");
            var sel = "#" + thename;
            $(this).click(function() {  //<--- On the <a/> not the hidden element
                alert("running click for element with value " + this.id);
                if ($(sel).is(":hidden")) { // <----you want to check the hidden not the <a/>
                    $(sel).slideDown("slow");
                } else {
                    $(sel).slideUp();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});​
```

**[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5Hejm/21/)**

Comment: that... is awesome! i'll mark this as the answer when i can (4 mins)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it :

```
$("div").each(function(idx) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('bio-readMore')) {
        var thename = this.id.replace("Btn", "Hidden");
        var sel = "#" + thename;
        console.log(sel);
        $(this).click(function() {
            if ($(sel).is(":hidden")) {
                $(sel).slideDown("slow");
            } else {
                $(sel).slideUp();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/jSGkn/)

You were confusing the element on which to click and the one to display/hide.

Comment: ahhhh, thanks. that makes sense now, i was banging my head on the wall figuring out where i was screwing that up!

Answer (score 1):

You were binding the click event to the hidden element.. What you need is to bind the click handler to the `..read more` div's and slideUp/Down based on the corresponding sections visibility.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/5Hejm/15/

```
    $('div.bio-readMore').click(function() {
        var thename = this.id.replace("Btn", "Hidden");
        var $sel = $("." + thename);
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($sel.is(":hidden")) {
            $sel.slideDown("slow");
            $this.text('...read less');
        } else {
            $sel.slideUp();
            $this.text('...read more');
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bio-readMore").click(function() {
            if ($(this).prev().is(":hidden")) {
                  $(this).prev().slideDown("slow");
                 $(this).text(" ...read less");
            } else {
                 $(this).prev().slideUp();
                  $(this).text(" ...read more");
            }
        });
});​
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5Hejm/31/